# Get taxonomy of post from list of multiple taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type **Music** with multiple taxonomies as **Genres**, **Artists**, **Types**.
I have multiples posts under them.

Suppose post **x** is under **Artists** taxonomy but not associated with **Genres** & **Types**. In this case how can i get the taxonomy name (Artists) but not Genres & Types with the help of post id(id of **x**)?

Is there any wp function or rule to get only Artists taxonomy?

Comment: You want to show the Artist for the post ? or you want to show the other related posts from the same term for Artists taxonomy for current post?

Comment: If it is the first case then easy check this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms  e.g //Returns Array of Term Names for "my_taxonomy"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "names"));
print_r($term_list);

Comment: Please i dont want to show term_list but want to know under which taxonomy my post is categorized.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the related taxonomy of a post by multiple functions, such as : `get_the_terms()` or `wp_get_post_terms()`.

Please find the code below:

**Using get_the_terms() function**

*Reference* : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

*Syntax*: `get_the_terms( int|object $post, string $taxonomy );`

*Example*:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy_name');
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
    echo $term->term_id;
}
```

OR

**Using wp_get_post_terms();**

*Reference* : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/

*Syntax* =>  `wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );`

*Example*:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy_name', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
    echo $term->term_id;
}
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you. Feel free to ask, if you have any query.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you response. But from your example `get_the_terms( int|object $post, string $taxonomy );` how would i know the `$taxonomy` cause i only know post id but not the taxonomy name it is related to from those multiple taxonomies. ANd my that's my actual question.

Comment: Do you actualy mean the above code of yours will eventually return me **Artists** taxonomy?

Comment: Genres, Artists & Types are only the terms of a Taxonomy. You will have a taxonomy 'name' or 'slug' under which these all taxonomy terms (Genres, Artists & Types) lie. Please find in the backend or where you have generated this taxonomy. Thanks and please let me know, if you have any query.

Comment: That is not helping me any more. Now please tell me from the above example of yours.`$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy_name', array("fields" => "all"));` . What is the value of ` taxonomy_name` since i have `$post->ID` ?

Comment: @rafin please tell how you have created the above taxonomies terms , through code or some plugin, if you have created the taxonomy through code, then please provide me the code or if you have used plugin then provide me plugin details, hope this may help me in resolving your issue.

Comment: There you go. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy. I followed standard way to create my custom post type and registered 3 taxonomies as above.

Comment: The slug which you have used in register_taxonomy() function will be written in place of 'taxonomy_name' in my function. For ex: For 'Genres' taxonomy, may be you have used like this : register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'music' ), $args ). So in my function, you will use : $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre', array("fields" => "all"));

Comment: For fulfilling your requirement, you have to create certain conditions, like this: $genres= wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre', array("fields" => "names")); if($genres) { echo "Genres"; }. And similarly for the other two taxonomies.

Comment: Friend, You are not actually getting what i want. You are right with `$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'genre', array("fields" => "all"));` but please that's not what i want. With that function it will list the `term` information of the post under `genre` taxonomy. But what if my post is not under `genre` and in `artist` ? Yeah i know i can use same `wp_get_post_terms()` replacing `genre` with `artist` but i cannot go using same function for each taxonomy that i registered to get the term. Is there any way i can figure out under which taxonomy(either `genre` or `artist`) my post is?

Comment: My output should be `genre` if my post is categorized under `genre` taxonomy but not the terms of genre. With that function of yours it will list the term in array not the taxonomy name it self.. YOU GETTING ME?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array( 'taxonomy_1', 'taxonomy_2', 'taxonomy_3', 'taxonomy_4' ) );
```

So basicly, just add all the taxonomy this post could be in and the array returned will list all taxonomies this post's in